# Java HashTable LoadFactor

Tags: java, data-structures

The Java Hashtable has a constructor where you can specify a loadFactor. However, if the initialCapacity (n) is known, what's the point of specifying the loadFactor?

Assuming that the size of its array of buckets (s) is constant, does the constructor  `Hashtable(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor)`
just create a Hash Table that has more capacity than initialCapacity to ensure the correct loadFactor?

Comment: The load factor says when to resize the array. A higher load factor means later resizing and more collisions.

Comment: what the question is asking, i think (and why i think this is an interesting question) is: do they really just follow use `initialCapacity` to give an initial size blindly?  because, if so, they are going to need to resize when `initialCapacity` values are added (unless loadFactor is 1).  so, assuming that `initialCapacity` is often an accurate estimate of how many values will be added, wouldn't it make more sense to calculate an initial size such that `initialCapacity` points can be added without resize?  in other words: does initial capacity mean initial *table size* or initial *capacity*?

Comment: @andrewcooke: I see what you mean, but according to [the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html), "The *capacity* is the number of *buckets* in the hash table" (italics in original), so there is no contradiction here -- only, perhaps, a poor choice of word.

Comment: you also say in your answer that they are only *hints*.  however, in practice, at least for gnu classpath, you are correct - http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/HashMap-source.html

Comment: sun is similar but rounds up to a power of 2 - http://kickjava.com/src/java/util/HashMap.java.htm

Comment: I did some more research, and this article seems to go into this into some detail: http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-hashtable/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Assuming that the size of its array of buckets (s) is constant, […]

This assumption is not correct. The array of buckets is resized when necessary to ensure that the proportion of non-empty buckets is at most `loadFactor`.

(Note: [the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) states that "The initial capacity and load factor parameters are merely hints to the implementation. The exact details as to when and whether the rehash method is invoked are implementation-dependent", so the above shouldn't be taken as a strict guarantee. But it's the general behavior.)

Answer (score 2):

Because it's only the *initial* capacity. The `HashMap` is a dynamic structure; you can exceed the initial capacity which is what the loadfactor is used for - to know when to expand.

(And the data structure has no way of divining your intentions if you mean to say *you* know that you're never going to exceed that initial capacity; it's a data structure, not a clairvoyant AI ;) ).

Answer (score -1):

If you know exactly the size of your table, then make the loadfactor 1. The class is written for everyone -- including the likely case that people will want to increase the size of the array.